# (iPhone)Instruments question

Tags: iphone, performance, instruments

Just wondering if my iPhone application should be running slow when I put it through instruments? When I test my app using instruments, it goes extremely slow and is frustrating to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal as Instruments is constantly monitoring the app's process, which causes the app to run considerably slower than normal.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation. When instrument gathers data, the app seems to hang up. And this is natural.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think that instruments affect your application being monitored. You can/should try in the real Iphone device to see the real performance

Comment: Yeah, I always run instruments when testing on the device. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey.
And more different instruments you load int Instruments the slower it gets.